# Kitchen Faucet Replacement Issues

Tags: repair, faucet, advice

I was trying to change my moms kitchen faucet and I encountered something I haven't seen before.

How exactly am I supposed to get this faucet off?

I figured I would try and get some advice here before getting someone to come in and do it.

[image: picture from directly below]

Comment: Normally those are "disconnect the plumbing" (pipes/hoses - larger hex nuts, use TWO wrenches so you don't twist the tubes) then remove the small hex nut away from the sink holding the U-shaped clamp (while someone holds the faucet from above to prevent it from doing damage when it falls over - or put a big towel around it) then you pull it up out of the hole, wiggling the connections through.The sprayer hose may disconnect elsewhere, or be easier to disconnect after pulling the faucet partway out of the hole.

Comment: Will it come off all the way? Or only turn a small amount. Also I have a faucet that I'm replacing it that has the big center mounting plate. That will work right? I don't need this same type of faucet?

Answer (score 0):

The long hexagonal nut has to be opened. It has 2 slits to accept a big screwdriver as well. It seems to be a faucet for a boiler or tankless heater,which might require an "open", i.e. pressureless faucet in order to enable the hot water to expand and leave during heating up. In that case a drippling is normal and not an indication for a defect faucet.

When reconnecting the hoses to the new faucet, these hoses must not be twisted, else they can fail after some time. These threaded connections do only need a low torque, sometimes the manuals forbid to take tools like spanners.